# Internet connection issues on Windows 8.1

Tags: firefox, windows-8.1, internet-connection, timeout

This has been happening to me for a while. I can't remember exactly when it started happening, but my dad recently installed the 8.1 update to his computer and he's having similar problems, so it probably happened to me back when I updated it (a couple of months ago now).

When I browse the internet, some sites don't connect the first time round. If I refresh the page a couple of times it works, and then after that I can browse that entire site easily. The thing is, it seems to happen with random websites. It can happen with one that I've never visited before, or something like Google, which is my homepage and probably the site I access most often. I use Firefox, and I get a page like this:

[image: TimedOut]

I get similar issues with IE though. This problem seems to "reset" itself each time I close the browser, and every site I visit seems to have a random chance of working the first time round.

I've tried a fix suggested [here](http://blog.rudnyi.ru/2013/11/update-to-windows-8-1.html), as well as the fix in the comment, both produce no results. I seem to be able to connect fine with other applications such as Skype, HipChat, Steam, and Blizzard's Battle.net client, as well as online games.

Anybody have any idea what's going on or how to fix it? I'm fairly confident that it's a Windows 8.1 issue.

Comment: Wired or wireless internet? If wireless, try plugging into your router directly and see if that changes anything. You might just be getting a weak signal from your router and it's dropping off.

Comment: Did you make sure the LAN and/or WLAN drivers are up to date?

Comment: @Adam: It's a wireless connection, but my connection seems solid. From my position I'm consistently getting 4-5 (full) bars, and I haven't seen it drop off at all.

Comment: @imtheman: I just checked and my network adapter seems to have its drivers up to date.

Comment: Testing over wireless is inherently unstable, there are too many factors that come into play even if you are getting 'full bars'. Intermittent problems such as this one are very commonly caused by using wireless. If you plugging into the network is the easiest way to tell if this is a wireless problem or something else.